# Refresh Parent form in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

In the parent contact form, I have a grid which has employment records. So, when grid is selected, the ribbon for employment appears.

When I click a record in the grid, after saving the values of employment, I want to refresh the contact form. On save event of employment, tried all the following properties:

```
window.parent.parent.location.reload(true), window.parent.location.reload(true)
```

This did not work, because for parent it is taking url as edit of employment entity.

So, I tried:

```
window.opener.parent.document.crmForm(), window.opener.parent.document.all.crmForm()
```

This gives me a javascript error as object id null.

Can you help me refresh the contact page on save of employment form?

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.parent.opener.document.location.reload(true)`. Works on UR13.

Be aware that if there are changes on contact form, you'll get message about unsaved changes on page before if will proceed with reload

Answer (score 0):

looks like you just need the following JavaScript:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```